# how do I echo $something >> file.txt without carriage return?

Tags: bash, redirection

When I `echo $something >> file.txt`, a new line will be append to the file.

What if I want to append without a new line?

Comment: Be careful doing `echo $something`, its behavior depends on the `IFS` variable, and you could end up with disappearing character.  You can try the following: `var="hello  world"; echo $var` (two spaces between hello and world) or `var="hello  world"; IFS='l'; echo $var` or `var="-e hello \\n world"; echo $var`.  To solve that, put double quotes around the variable like this: `echo "$var"`, or use `printf`.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

That's what `echo -n` is for .

Comment: Is there an equivalent for `cat`? (e.g. when you have a file `something.txt` rather than a variable `$something`)

Comment: @cboettig: No. Use a different tool to print everything but the final newline.

Comment: @cboettig , cat does not add anything to the output by default, so there is no need for a '-n' param for cat. eg, if your file does not have a line-ending in the last line, then your shell prompt will be printed right after the last character of the file and not in a new line

Answer (score 47):

[`printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf-141) is very flexible and more portable than `echo`. Like the C/Perl/etc implementations, if you do not terminate the format string with `\n` then no newline is printed:

```
printf "%s" "$something" >> file.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using command's output, you can use xargs in combination with echo

```
/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }' | xargs echo -n >> /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

`tr` is another alternative.

If you're using `echo` as your input you can get away which `tr -d '\n'`.

This technique also works when piping in output from other commands (with only a single line of output). Moreover, if you don't know whether the files have UNIX or DOS line endings you can use `tr -d '\n\r'`.

**Here are some tests showing that this works.**

Newline included:

```
something='0123456789' ; echo ${something} | wc -c
11
```

UNIX newline:

```
something='0123456789' ; echo ${something} | tr -d '\n\r' | wc -c
10
```

DOS style:

```
something='0123456789' ; echo ${something} | unix2dos | tr -d '\n\r' | wc -c
10
```

Tested with BSD `tr` and GNU `tr`.